# jQuery text decoration underline in navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When mouse enter one of li About Portfolio Contact how to make text-decoration underline. Also how to control the speed of underline and what if I want just 1/3 of the word to be decorated by underline? Am I thinking right? Please help!

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li id="btnabout"><a href="#parallax"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
    <li id="btnportfolio"><a href="#portfolio"><strong>Portfolio</strong></a></li>
    <li id="btncontact"><a href="#contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('navbar-collspse').mouseenter(function(){
    $(#btnabout).css("text-decoration", underline");
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you knew you can do it by simply using CSS `:hover`? ...P.S: `$('navbar-collspse')` is missing a class selector `.`

Comment: I can but it is my first project and I would like to use jQuery for that. My first jQuery as well. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Anything you can achieve with CSS should be done by CSS, as it is in general much faster for these tasks as Javascript is. So try @RokoC.Buljan's approach.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ok I will do it by CSS but please can you help me with jQuery code. I'm wondering whether am right or not.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  Also how to control the speed of underline and what if I want just 1/3 of the word to be decorated by underline?

Comment: @EdgarKiljak see my example using CSS `transition: 0.3s;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
.nav li a:hover{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

if the line should span only `1/3` the width, than use a `a:after` pseudo to create your line

```css
.nav li{
  display:inline-block;
}
.nav li a{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a:after{
  content: "";
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left:16px;  /* = padding size */
  height: 1px;
  width:0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  background: blue;
}
.nav li a:hover:after{
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li id="btnabout"><a href="#parallax"><b>About</b></a></li>
  <li id="btnportfolio"><a href="#portfolio"><b>Portfolio</b></a></li>
  <li id="btncontact"><a href="#contact"><b>Contact</b></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Roko. I've done it in CSS way. But with jQuery here doesn't look like the speed or transition is controlled and no color option. Also please can you explain the purpose of  content " " in your CSS.

Comment: @EdgarKiljak you're welcome. The `:before` and `:after` pseudos use the `content` CSS property to generate / paint that pseudo element. If you set to `content : "Hello"` that `Hello` would appear, therefore and empty string is needed - to make use of the pseudo el. but without actual text Content

Comment: @EdgarKiljak for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content

Comment: Much appreciated. Learned something today for sure! See your contribution to my very first website: http://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/pEXLNY?editors=1100 Basically I'm going free code camp and that is my first project.

Comment: @EdgarKiljak I like your enthusiasm! You also have a good sense for design. Keep it up! Learn learn learn and build beautiful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple CSS `:hover` to give underline to your text:

```
.nav li a:hover{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

For controlling style change speed, you can use [CSS transition](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).
Althought be sure to check if it works with property you want to change.
If you want to underline only part of the text, you can create another element inside it, add some styles so it looks like underline and give it proper width and change it's opacity on hover.

**HTML**

```
<li id="btnabout">
   <a href="#parallax">
     <strong>About<span class="underline"></span></strong>
   </a>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
li a strong { position: relative; }
.underline { 
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0; /* you can move it to the left/right here as you wish */
  height: 1px;
  width: 33%; /* for 1/3 width */
  background-color: /* Your font color here */;
  transition: opacity .3s linear; /* remember to use webkits */
}  
li a:hover .underline {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.navbar-collapse ul li a:hover{
      text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li id="btnabout"><a href="#parallax"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
                <li id="btnportfolio"><a href="#portfolio"><strong>Portfolio</strong></a></li>
                <li id="btncontact"><a href="#contact"><strong>Contact</strong></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
```